# Does this imply that $a<b$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(u_{n})_{n≥1}$ be a strictly increasing sequence. Let $a,b$ two integers such that $a<b$, then we have $u_{a}<u_{b}$. Now assuming that $u_{a}<u_{b}$. Does this imply that $a<b$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. If $a<b$ is false then $a \geq b$. But then  $u_a \geq u_b$ and this is a contradiction. BTW strictly increasing is not necessary! Increasing will do!.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, since your sequence is strictly increasing.